Why doesn't Suspense work on deployed NextJS projects
I am trying to use Suspense in NextJS but the fallback component is not getting mounted at all.
I have added a 2 second timer, and instead of seeing the fallback component for 2 seconds, the page just loads for 2 seconds before showing the component wrapped in <Suspense>
If I build this locally and run it, it works. However I tried uploading the code on Vercel, DigitalOcean, and codesandbox, and in all instances the fallback component is not loaded.
I even tried adding this code I found here, but it didn't help neither https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying#streaming-and-suspense
codesandbox link
package.json
{
  "name": "test-suspense",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "14.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.5"
  }
}


next.config.mjs
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  headers: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:path*{/}?",
        headers: [
          {
            key: "X-Accel-Buffering",
            value: "no",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
};

export default nextConfig;


dashboard/page.tsx
import DashboardView from "@/components/DashboardView";
import { Suspense } from "react";

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export default async function page() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={"Loading..."}>
      <DashboardView />
    </Suspense>
  );
}


DashboardView.tsx
import Link from "next/link";

const getData = async () => {
  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 2000));
};

export default async function DashboardView() {
  await getData();
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Dashboard View</p>
      <div>
        <Link href="/">Home</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}



Did you figure this out?
